# WinForm: Open the Form3 in Form1 panel with the Form2

Tags: winforms, panel

I open Form2 into panel1 of Form1.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string OpenCurrentForm = "01";
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Open Form1 
            OpenCurrentForm = "01";
            OpenForm();
        }

        private void OpenForm()
        {
            Form childFormAll;
            childFormAll = new Test_Open_Forms.Forms.Schlepper.Form2();
            if (OpenCurrentForm == "01")
            {
                childFormAll = new Test_Open_Forms.Forms.Schlepper.Form2();
            }
            if (OpenCurrentForm == "02")
            {
                childFormAll = new Test_Open_Forms.Forms.Schlepper._02();
            }
            childFormAll.TopLevel = false;
            childFormAll.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(childFormAll);
            this.panel1.Tag = childFormAll;
            childFormAll.BringToFront();
            childFormAll.Show();
        }
    }
```

Form2 contains a button, which I now like to use to close Form2 and load Form3 into panel1 of Form1

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO:: Open Form 01 in panel1 form Form1
        }
    }
```

How do I achieve this?

Can I somehow access the panel1 with the Form2?
Or the function that opens the forms?
What is the most elegant version?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/